# JavaScript flowchart / flow diagram lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, workflow, flowchart

Are there any javascript libraries for client-side rendering and manipulation of flow-charts?  My preference would be for jQuery, but I'd settle for others.

---

This question has been asked before, but not for a couple of years so I'm hoping there's a more positive answer now!

---

The question *has* been asked *again* and now the most upvoted and most complete version of this question and answers is here:
[Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, [WireIt](http://neyric.github.com/wireit/) looks like the best bet.  Mentioned also here: [Designing a Yahoo Pipes inspired interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86361/designing-a-yahoo-pipes-inspired-interface)

Answer (score 26):

The following JavaScript libraries may help :)

- [Jit](http://thejit.org/)
- [jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org)

Answer (score 12):

[mxGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph), which is written in plain JavaScript, so you could wrap it in jQuery or any JS framework. It's Apache 2.0 licensed.

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) for this.

Sweet sexy demo: http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

Comment: its really hard to even create a flow chart with this.. quickly to just use divs / css

Answer (score 0):

Extjs lib. An example online flow chart build with  [extjs](http://www.cubedrive.com/flowPublic?id=HQypsxuhMgQ_&viewStatus=publicView)

And online flow chart help document [here](http://www.cubedrive.com/wordPublic?id=mN8TqLcVN-4_&viewStatus=publicView).