# Python/JavaScript/HTML create a computer network diagram dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I want to create a computer network diagram dynamically on UI, with the network diagram having switches, routers and other devices and these devices are connected with links and i need to label these links at both ends of the devices being connected by a particular link.

I am open to creating this image from backend, I have python for backend, with any image creation library. Though i would still prefer if there is any way to do it with any JS module, if available. In python i came across one library PIL.

Could you please point me to any JS modules that can help me do this, or any python module which would best suite the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this link might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86361/designing-a-yahoo-pipes-inspired-interface

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [RaphaelJS Javascript library](http://raphaeljs.com), which uses SVG under the covers. Their website have an example with a graph which may be a good starting point to your diagram creation code: http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html That's what I'd recommend for doing it in the client side.

If you actually were to do in the backend with Python, you could look for a solution using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) under the covers, maybe [python-graph](https://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Example) or [pydot](https://code.google.com/p/pydot/).